# Does the line bundle have global sections?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a smooth projective surface over $\mathbb{C}$. Let $H$ be an ample divisor on $X$. Consider a line bundle $N$ such that $N\cdot H>0$ and $H^2(N)=0$. Is it possible that $H^0(N)=0$? I feel it is not possible because $N\cdot H>0$ should mean $N$ is effective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. Let me start by cooking up an example and then I will address your last sentence.

Let $X$ be a quartic in $\mathbf P^3$ containing two disjoint lines $L_1$ and $L_2$. (Note that $X$ is a K3 surface.) Let $N$ be the line bundle associated to the divisor $2L_1-L_2$. Let $H$ be the restriction of the hyperplane class to $X$. Then:

- $H \cdot N =1$
- $H^0(N)=0$
- $H^2(N)=H^0(N^\ast)=0$.

---

As for: "I feel it is not possible because $N⋅H>0$ should mean $N$ is effective.":

This inequality is certainly a *necessary* condition for a (nontrivial) line bundle to be effective, but it is (almost always) not *sufficient*.

There is an vector space $N^1(X)$ of numerical classes of line bundles. For a given line bundle $H$ the condition $N \cdot H >0$ defines an open half-space $H_{>0}$ inside $N^1(X)$. If $H$ is ample then the numerical class of any effective line bundle must be in $H_{>0}$. But in fact the set of numerical classes of effective line bundles is much smaller: it is a strictly convex cone inside $H_{>0}$, called the *effective cone*. In general the structure of this cone can be very complicated.

A good reference to learn more is Volume I of *Positivity in Algebraic Geometry* by Lazarsfeld.

Comment: Thanks for the really detailed answer. Does it make any difference if $X$ is a principally polarized Abelian surface and $H$ is the polarisation?

Comment: No, I do not believe it makes a difference. As long as the Picard number (i.e. the dimension of $N^1(X)$ is at least 2, one can find a line bundle $N$ such that $N \cdot H >0$ and neither $N$ nor $N^*$ has a section. This is just a matter of drawing a half-space and a strictly positive cone inside it.

Comment: ah I see. If Picard number is one, then is it possible to find $N$ as described? That is if $N.H>0$ and the line bundle and its dual doesn’t have sections.

Comment: If the Picard number is 1, then every bundle is either ample or the dual of an ample bundle.

Comment: Oops, I meant to say in the previous comment "every numerically nontrivial bundle".

Comment: Thank you for the discussion!